# Is there a way to disable autoplay?

Tags: xbox-360, netflix

Is there a way to disable autoplay in the Fall 2011 revision of the Xbox 360 Netflix client?

Comment: Huh. This article is the top google result for "netflix autoplay xbox".

Comment: Don't you have to go all the way into the description of a movie, and then intentionally select it to play? Once you've gone in to the "I want to stare at the first frame of the movie in the movie player" state, you're "watching it" AFAIC. It'd be a ridiculous ux to add yet ANOTHER button click after going all the way into the player to start it. I'd say 1 of 1000 people want another click to just watching a film.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a nice X on movie covers in your "recently watched" list, in the way you can remove something from your queue.

Comment: @SeanGallagher I don't follow. All I want is the behavior of the prior version of the application, as that worked quite well. The new version runs contrary to 20+ years of GUI training, so I find it difficult and annoying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can now be done but it must be done through the Netflix website itself (this is not available in apps for iOS, Xbox, FireTV, etc).

Go to account settings and then you'll find the auto-play option under playback settings. Here's a 2 minute video showing [how to disable auto-play](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-MMR0IrSNk). And here's the official [Netflix instructions](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/2102) for it.

Answer (score 5):

In the current form, there are no options, or menus to change any options for the Netflix Xbox 360 application related to autoplay, or anything else for that matter.

I would hope this is an oversight that will be fixed, because I didn't really want to start and play *Hot in Cleveland* and have it stuck in my Recently Watched section for eternity.

Comment: I didn't think so, but I had to ask.

Comment: @CyberSkull Hoping they'll update it. I'll try and remember to update this if they ever do.

Comment: @CyberSkull was excited to see the April Netflix update, but alas... no way to turn off auto-play still.

Comment: I know, all they did was add bigger preview frames. :(

Comment: I think the thing that kills me most about this is once it starts auto playing, there's no where you can go where it won't auto play your selection. It's like playing hot potato. I guess Netflix wants us to close the app out of frustration all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Call their hotline to complain and request to make the feature optional. I just did and had a great call with the customer service. They have received a lot of calls/feedback that is strongly against the feature, or at least strongly pushing to make it optional (toggle on/off). Customer service number: 1-866-579-7115